# Can I pass $(this) to the .getJSON callback function? any workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to get the value of rel on each li and pass it to the .getJSON function. I then want to add the thumbnail_url value from the callback to the image tag of the li descendants . My question is how could I pass the $(this) object to the callback function. It seems the $(this) is null.

```
$('ul.sample li').each(function () {

        var url = 'http://sampleurl/api/url?' + $(this).attr('rel');

        $.getJSON(url, function (data){
            $(this).find('img').attr('src') = data.thumbnail_url;
    })
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sample">
   <li rel="value1">
       <img src="">
   </li>
   <li rel="value2">
       <img src="">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(unexpected_token_identifier)

Comment: Javascript closures strike again!

Comment: Besides the original issue, you also have another problem:  It should be `var url = 'http://sampleurl/api/url?'+$(this).attr('rel');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just assign it outside of the callback (like I am setting `self`) and then use inside callback (by referring to the variable you have set):

```
$('ul.sample li').each(function () {

    var self = $(this); // using self to store $(this)
    var url = 'http://sampleurl/api/url?' + self.attr('rel');

    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        // now retrieving self - it is accessible from the callback
        self.find('img').attr('src') = data.thumbnail_url;
    });

});
```

The reason for that is because `this` is different in callback for `.each()` than in callback for `$.getJSON()`.

Comment: Just want to point out that you copied an error in the OPs code.  It should be `var url = 'http://sampleurl/api/url?'+$(this).attr('rel');`

Comment: @Steve: You are right, I indeed have copied OP's code by fixing what did not work for him.

Comment: by convention you should use the variable name 'that' instead of 'self'

Comment: Optimization suggestion: Move `self=$(this)` to the top of the function and change the `url` assignment to `self.attr('rel')`.  It minifies better.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive  What convention is that?  While I also use `that`, I have seen both variables used in the wild a lot. jQuery itself uses `self` all over the place.

Comment: I take guidance from 'JavaScript: The Good Parts' http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive, With respect, Crockford is not Always Right.  In practice, you'll see `self` used as much as `that` to hold on to `this`.   I prefer `self` since it has closer grammatical meaning to `this` than does `that`, and is therefore less confusing and more readable.

Comment: i've never seen self, but there is not rule.  write it how you'd like

Comment: remember this site? googlefight... http://googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=var+that+%3D+this&word2=var+self+%3D+this

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive - That's what I thought. :) The reason I use `that` is because I was trained under Douglas at Yahoo!  But as you point out, there is no hard rule.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: To be fair, number of Google hits is an awful metric for something like this.  (Once you get past the first page, most results have absolutely nothing to do with JS.)  A better idea is to compare [`that`](https://github.com/search?q=that%3Dthis&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=JavaScript) and [`self`](https://github.com/search?q=self%3Dthis&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=JavaScript) usage on GitHub -- 2k vs 64k.

Comment: In jQuery, I like `$this` actually. But anyway... `self` defaults to `window`. Interesting, no?

Answer (score 7):

If you use `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON`, you could use the `context` option:

```
$('ul.sample li').each(function () {
    var url = 'http://sampleurl/api/url?' + $(this).attr('rel');
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        context : this,
        complete : function (data) {
            // 'this' will be what you passed as context 
            $(this).find('img').attr('src') = data.thumbnail_url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any other major difference between these $.ajax() and #.getJSON() functions?

Comment: Well, `$.ajax` is more verbose, as you can see. On this example, I passed the options required to make it behave exactly like `getJSON`, but [there are many other options available](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). `$.get`, `$.post` and `$.getJSON` are basically wrappers to `$.ajax`.